# how to pass formula which is in group of main report to sub report (crystal report)

Tags: crystal-reports

This question about crystal report.
I have crystal report, which has a formula in Group Section. I want to show all the generated group names in bottom of the crystal report.
So I have insert subreport to Main report footer. Then created a formula and link it to main report 
formula. 
But When running, in sub report, only show last generated group name only. 
How to print all the generated group names in bottom of the report.

Thank you.

Comment: A sub report in the Main Report Footer WILL only print the last value. If you wish to print it for every group, you need to put the sub report in the footer of the GROUP section.

Comment: I have tried that way. Then I can print every groups. But then, sub report is printing after each group. But I want to print sub report, after all the group have print of main .

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you intend to do, you have a few options:

- add a Cross-tab to the Report-Footer section - this will summarized the report's data without a second trip to the database
- add a sub-report to the Report-Footer section - you will have more control of the formatting, but it will require a second trip to the database
- create a formula that executes at print time (WhileReadingRecords) to store the group names in an array (note: arrays hold a maximum of 1000 entries), then create a second formula (also print time), that joins the array, adding it to the Report-Footer section.